# Work with two different branches and merging them?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge, git-branch

I have two different branches: `clean` and `dev`. The difference between those two branches is that `clean` removes all the bloat, unnecessary features, and comments within the components while `dev` keeps the comments and testing features.

What I intend on doing is that somehow, when I add a new feature, I'm gonna add it to `clean` and `dev` branch so we have the new features both with and without the bloat and documentation. I'm lost on how to do that actually.

Answer (score 4):

Since `clean` is `dev` with some stuff edited out, the easiest way is, each time you are ready in `dev`, checkout `clean`, merge `dev` into `clean`, and then edit the stuff out and (still in `clean`) add and commit. Now checkout `dev` and carry on.